# How to resolve the error from changing target version of a project in a solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version, build-error

In the project I am currently working on, there are several projects in the solution. I had to change the target version of a particular project, which is responsible for handling particular APIs of the project, for installing certain Nuget Packages.

Now there are some .dll not found errors coming when I try to run the project.

How can I resolve this issue?
My project is based on .net framework and I am using Visual Studio 2017.

My actual Target version was .NET Framwork 4.5.1. 
I had to change it to 4.6.1 since the package I was trying to install IBM.Watson.NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.v1 -Version 4.2.1 package.

Errors are like this:

> Metadata file 'location\ProjectName.dll' could not be found.

Comment: You need to be more specific, can you please explain what target versions you have and how they are dependent

Comment: Please state your exisiting .net version , the target version, nuget package your installing and the complete error that you see about the dll

Comment: @Clint I have updated the details you asked for in the question. Kindly look into it.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I have updated the details

Comment: Doea metda data file could not be found occurs during installation of nuget ? And nuget installation stops due to that right ?

Comment: @Clint No. Not compatible with the current version error comes when I install with 4.5.1 Target version.

Comment: "Not compatible with current version" ? but you stated that the error was "Metda data file could not be found" could you clarify

Comment: @Clint "Not compatible with current version" An error similar to this comes when I try to install the Nuget Packages on Target Version 4.5.1. So, I changed the Target version to 4.6.1. And after changing the Target Version to 4.6.1, I get "Meta data file could not be found" error when I run the project. I hope you understood the issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My actual Target version was .NET Framwork 4.5.1. I had to change it
>   to 4.6.1 since the package I was trying to install
>   IBM.Watson.NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.v1 -Version 4.2.1 package.

*I recreated the problem by attempting to install the nuget on a new console app targeting .netframework 4.6.1 and it failed*

*This is where problem lies, **`IBM Watson NaturalLanguageUnderstanding`** is compatible with **`.NETStandard 2.0 Specification`*** which means you would need to target 4.6.1 (*2) ideally, but here is the catch (as explained  here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard))

[image]

---

***2 ways to solve this***

- Target .NetFramework 4.7.1 as recommended by the MSDN above **OR**
- If you want to use 4.6.1 then you would need to add this to your .CSPROJ file

```
<PropertyGroup>
     .
     .
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: 4.6.1 worked for me on a sample console application. But that's not the real problem I am facing. My problem is that, since I changed the target version of the project, the other projects that depend on this particular project are giving errors. I need to resolve those errors.

Comment: @StarLord join my chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207399/clint-clarifications

Comment: @StarLord following up to see if the extension helped out as per our discussion on chat.

Comment: @StarLord, hey long time, that's great. thanks for letting me know. if you could also mark the answer as resolved, so that it acts as a resolved reference for others in the future.
Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issues, change the target frameworks of the projects that are dependent on the project for which the target framework was changed. In most cases, there won't be much problem since Microsoft gives backward compatibility. There might be some problems with third-party NuGet packages. Also, some reference errors might come when deployed.